# ¿Cómo inserto datos a una sublista?

Tags: c++

Necesito insertar datos a una sublista, pero no sé cómo.
Tengo 2 structs Nodo; NodoAlumnos y NodoMaterias, compuestos de la siguiente forma:

```
struct NodoMaterias
{
    Materia info; // informacion de la materia
    NodoMaterias *siguiente; // puntero al siguiente nodo
};

struct NodoAlumnos
{
    Alumno info; // informacion del alumno
    NodoAlumnos *siguiente; // puntero al siguiente nodo
    NodoMaterias *siguienteM; // puntero al subnodo de Materia
};
```

Por ahora estoy consiguiendo añadir un nodo a la sublista. El problema es que me sobreescribe el nodo anterior, es decir que actualmente solo puede haber un único nodo, y no es lo que estoy buscando.
Mi procedimiento es el siguiente:

```
NodoMaterias *nuevo_nodoM=new NodoMaterias();
nuevo_nodoM->info=m;
materia_alumno->siguienteM=nuevo_nodoM; // materia_alumno es la dirección del NodoAlumno al que quiero agregarle los datos
inicioA=materia_alumno;
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se marca el final de una lista? ¿El puntero `siguiente` apunta a `nullptr`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Sí, se verifica que un puntero auxiliar apunte a vacío

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En general, para añadir un nodo al final de una lista de nodos, simplemente tienes que recorrer los nodos hasta dar con el último, una vez localizado el último:

1. Crear un nuevo nodo.
2. Enlazar el último con el nuevo.

Dado que no pareces estar guardando el último nodo, las operaciones necesarias acaban ahí. El código podría parecerse a:

```
void NuevaMateria(NodoMaterias *raiz, const Materia &m)
{
    if (NodoMaterias *ultimo = raiz)
    {
        // Mientras exista un nodo más adelante, avanza.
        while (ultimo->siguiente)
            ultimo = ultimo->siguiente;

        ultimo->siguiente = new NodoMaterias{m, nullptr};
    }
    else
        // Es el primer nodo insertado
        raiz = new NodoMaterias{m, nullptr};
}
```

Así que, cuando se quiera añadir una materia a un alumno, asumiendo que `Alumno` y `Materia` es construible por defecto, bastará con:

```
NodoAlumnos na{{}, nullptr, nullptr};
NuevaMateria(na.siguienteM, Materia{});
```

Comment: Es verdad, me había olvidado de eso! Ahora me está insertando bien los datos, muchas gracias!